# Share the clipboards automatically when using Apple Screen Sharing?

Tags: screen-sharing

Is it possible to share the clipboard of my local machine and a remote machine automatically when using OS X's built-in Screen Sharing utility? The whole Edit -> Send Clipboard, Edit -> Get Clipboard routine starts to feel a little cumbersome if you're doing any regular copy and paste work between your local desktop and a remote session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature seems to now exist in Apple Screen Sharing Version 1.5 (481.1)

`Edit > Use Shared Clipboard`

Or `View > Show Toolbar` and then select `Use Shared Clipboard`

[image: Use Shared Clipboard]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like the clipboard can be shared automatically. However, instead of going Edit->Send Clipboard and Edit->Get Clipboard, you can use the get/send clipboard buttons:

[image]

They're usually hidden by default, but you can get them to appear by clicking this button in the upper right hand corner of the window:
[image] or going View->Show Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you might want to switch to *JollysFastVNC*, which supports pasteboard sync out of the box: http://www.jinx.de/JollysFastVNC.html

Note that it is not free of charge.
You can also get it in the Mac App Store, where the home version (up to 7 computers) costs US-$ 9.99.

Comment: I [just went through getting Screen Sharing to work for me so I could cut JollysFastVNC out of my workflow](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5966/mac-to-mac-screen-sharing-doesnt-work-just-hangs). :) If possible I'd like to not go back to a paid VNC solution. Plus, I do like that CMD+key combos work with OS X's Screen Share (it never did with JollysFast for me).