# Share the clipboard with the remote accessed computer?

Tags: remote-desktop, copy-paste

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Share the clipboards automatically when using Apple Screen Sharing?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8412/share-the-clipboards-automatically-when-using-apple-screen-sharing)

Is there a way to have a shared clipboard with the computer you have accessed with Remote Desktop ? I tried to use those 2 buttons on the top of the screen to send and reveived what I cut and paste... Can It be set once for all ?